# make flex item extend to full document height when inside fixed position

Tags: css

I want to make white box extends to full document height when inside fixed position element ".justblack"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body {
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                height: 100%;
                flex: 1;
            }
            .main {
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .justblack {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.5);
                z-index: 94;
                overflow: scroll;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .inner {
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                width: 600px;
                border: 0;
                box-shadow: 0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                max-width: 60vw;
                padding: 30px;
                background: #fff;
            }
            section {
                padding: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="justblack">
                <div class="inner">
                    <section>some data</section>
                    <section>more data</section>
                    <section>this data</section>
                    <section>that data</section>
                    <section>no data</section>
                    <section>red data</section>
                    <section>blue data</section>
                    <section>green data</section>
                    <section>yellow data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>black data</section>
                    <section>brown data</section>
                    <section>important data</section>
                    <section>nice data</section>
                    <section>beautiful data</section>
                    <section>gray data</section>
                    <section>byebye data</section>
                    <section>game data</section>
                    <section>change data</section>
                    <section>none data</section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem with this code is that the white box will be cut off when you scroll down, like this

[image]

How can I fix so that the white box will extend fully, not get cut off like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `height: fit-content;` to the inner class fixed the issue!

If you are against the above fix, you can try this alternate fix

```
.inner {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  max-width: 60vw;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute; /* <- changed here */
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.justblack {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.5);
  z-index: 94;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  max-width: 60vw;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  height: fit-content; /* <- changed here */
}

section {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="justblack">
      <div class="inner">
        <section>some data</section>
        <section>more data</section>
        <section>this data</section>
        <section>that data</section>
        <section>no data</section>
        <section>red data</section>
        <section>blue data</section>
        <section>green data</section>
        <section>yellow data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>black data</section>
        <section>brown data</section>
        <section>important data</section>
        <section>nice data</section>
        <section>beautiful data</section>
        <section>gray data</section>
        <section>byebye data</section>
        <section>game data</section>
        <section>change data</section>
        <section>none data</section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```